# Stopping firewall on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, firewalld, firewall-cmd

I am having a problem with my CentOS 7 server

By accident i run command

```
# firewalld
```

Then i found that the log file in /var/log/firewalld was updated with the following

> 2020-11-26 12:59:08 WARNING: AllowZoneDrifting is enabled. This is considered an insecure configuration option. It will be removed in a future release. Please consider disabling it now.

**I checked the firewall status, which gave me inactive**

```
# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
```

**but when I checked firewall-cmd it says it is running**

```
# firewall-cmd --state
running
```

I tried to stop it using following command but nothing changed

```
    systemctl stop firewalld 
    systemctl disable firewalld
```

Any idea how to stop the firewall?

Your help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely the case where the process is hanging even is the service is disabled. Due to the firewall being started manually not using the daemon.

So run `ps aux |grep firewalld` and kill that process.

Comment: Thank you so much this is fixed my problem

Comment: More accurate is that the daemon was started manually and not as a service managed by systemd. Since firewalld was not running  from a managed service unit attempting to use systemd to stop it were unsuccessful.

Comment: @HermanB that is right the firewall was started by me manually accidently and not through service